# How to detect collisions with a curve

Tags: javascript, html, math, collision

I am making an HTML5 and Javascript platform game. At this moment all blocks of the map are handled as squares. This method is "ugly" when the block is not an exact square/rectangle.

Check this image I made to get a better understand of my point:

[image]
**Case one:** The "bottom bumper" is touching the square that envolves the block so the movement is stopped.

**Case two:** If I use the same method as above, when the players jumps, the movement will be stopped before the "top bumper" even touches the block.

How should I approach **case two**? I know that I have to check if the "Top Bumper" is colliding **OR inside the area between the curve and the other 2 edges**.

How would that curve be? How can I generate a function for it based on the block coordinates (x,y) and dimensions (width, height).

**Note:** I would like to avoid checking for collisions in every point of that curve because that would be very expensive for the CPU.

Comment: I like this question. How are you generating the curves (and other boundaries)? Are they images or are they created by a mathematical function? How many different kinds of blocks are you expecting to use?

Comment: @ChadMcGrath Hey, thanks for you reply. I want to use around 10-15 different blocks that are not perfect squares/rectangles. I am using images PNG but I also have the vector version of this images (SVG) that I don´t use .

Comment: There's some code out there for detection collisions with bezier curves, which is what svg uses to generate them. Essentially, it looks like you find the min/max values from the derivative of a function. Dunno if there's a javascript library for that yet, but if your SVG path's don't have too many parts I think it's very doable depending on how many curves you have on the screen (your one image looks like it only has 1 curve). The jagged ones, we can just detect for line segments. We could also cheat by only looking for objects that have collided with their bounding box.

Comment: A good resource for Bezier curves is http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ Sections 24 and 25 describe intersection methods.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possibilities, depending on how "perfect" you want your collisions to be and how portable and labor-intensive you want the technique to be. By no means is this comprehensive, these are just the ones I would personally evaluate. I've used the first two personally.

1. Use line segments to approximate your curve. Create "vertices" along the curve, and make line segments out of each pair of them. You already know how to test against axis-aligned squares, it's not a huge leap to move to testing to see if any of your characters points are "behind" a collider line segment (similar to checking if points are "behind" a plane). You can get surprisingly accurate and performant results with this (depending on how granularly you generate line segments), the hardest part is generating the collision map in the first place. I chose to hand-define the segments, which I consider a mistake. If i were to do it again, I'd probably try to find a way to generate the line segments, given some settings about how granular I want them.
2. Calculate the *outline* of the curve, and create colliders 1px by 1px for each pixel of the curve. This is your collision map. Use a circle or ellipsis for the collision mesh of your character, and check distance between the colliders and character. This simplifies the calculations quite a lot, and although we're talking about a *lot* of possible calculations (one check per pixel), a lot of optimization can be had by aggressively spatially partitioning your world (bin, bsp, whatever). Generation of this is relatively straightforward image edge detection, so you wind up with a near-drop-in solution. I used this in a Spy Hunter ripoff, and the artist greatly appreciated the ability to just make art and not worry heavily about collisions.
3. Pixel diffs. I've never actually done this, but I've seen talks of
   "pdiffing" where the character sprite and tile sprites are overlaid
   in-memory, and if there is any overlap between non-transparent areas
   of either, it indicates a collision. Depending on the size of your
   sprites, this may become prohibitively expensive. It also would
   probably only work in the context of a tile-based game.

Comment: If only checking the four bumbers, the pixel-based method is probably even the fastest and easiest method.